# No more inetpub logs created after W3SVC99

Tags: iis, logging, x-forwarded-for

I am currently migrating sites to Windows Server 2016. Running IIS 10.0.14393.0.

All sites in application pools above the ID of 99 do not have a folder inside C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles. These sites are running as usual, but the traffic is not causing the folder or log files to be created.

Sites with an ID between 1 and 99 are continuing to create *.log files.

Answer (score 0):

At site Level, under Logging, Select Fields, we had added an extra field for x-forwarded-for. When we removed this extra field. The app pools immediately created new folders for logging.